# Trying to write a JS dice game that compares current roll array against all previous rolls, until a set number of unique rolls have been reached

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, string-comparison

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out. I'm new to coding so might be an obvious mistake.

The goal is to:

Make an array of more than 1 elements or a current roll
Compare it to an array of arrays containing previous rolls or prevs
If there are any exact matches, roll again.
If there are no matches, push current into prevs, add 1 to the successful roll count, and continue.
This process repeats until the number of unique rolls hits the goal number.
I feel like I'm stuck on the compare function.

I'm first using a for loop to iterate through the arrays in prevs to compare them against current If any match is found, return a 0 for unique, which cause the main while loop to not advance, due to the counter cnt staying the same. But if no matches are found, then I push current into prevs, return 1 for unique, which causes cnt to increase by 1 and the while loop to advance.

The logic in my mind is the current roll must only be compared to previous ones, before it's pushed into the array, otherwise there will always be a match, and the while loop will go on forever.

But for some reason, when I test with console.log to see the contents of the arrays being compared, the current roll and the previous roll is always the same. I can't figure out how this is happening.

Thank you so much for reading all this, and I appreciate any pointers you could give.

Here is my code:

```
var cnt=0; //number of successes
var current=[]; //array for the latest roll
var prevs=[[]]; //array of arrays of all previous unique rolls
var unique=1; //whether the latest roll is unique
var breaker; //emergency stopper for while loop
var goal=5;
var cnt=0;

function compare() { //checks the latest roll array against all previous arrays
    for (var i=0;i<prevs.length;i++) { //iterate through previous rolls, comparing each against the current roll, returning 0 for unique if any are a match
        if (compareArrays(current,prevs[i])) {
            return 0; 
        }
    }

    prevs.push(current); //if no matches are found, add the latest roll into the previous rolls
    return 1; //return a unique
}

function compareArrays(a,b) { //turn arrays into strings to compare
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
};

function dice() { //rolls a random number
  var min = Math.ceil(1);
  var max = Math.floor(10);
  var toss = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)); 
  return toss;
}

function main() { //main function
  while (cnt<goal) {
    breaker++;   
    if (breaker>50) { //this is here in case of emergency 
      break; 
    }
    
    current[0]=dice();     //first roll, two elements added to current roll array
    current.push(dice());
   
    unique=compare();   //run the compare function
    if (unique) { 
       console.log("Rolled unique, continuing.");
    cnt++; //only continue the count if roll was unique
    } else {
        console.log("Rolled duplicate, retrying.");
    }
    
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: This code wont run because `goal` is undefined in your `main()` function

Comment: Thanks for catching that, my test code actually has definitions for goal and cnt, I've updated the post to reflect that now.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve here, the description is confusing. `current[0]=dice(); //first roll` - why are you call this the _first_ roll, when you are doing it in _every_ loop iteration? Sure, you are only writing to the first array element here - but after that, you do a push, so in the first loop iteration you will have two values, three in the second, etc. Should `current` not get reset/emptied somewhere in all this?

Comment: Hi Cbroe, I should've specified that I wanted to roll two dice each time. You're right, I forgot to include something to reset the current array, it should be something like ```current.length=0;``` added right after comparing the roll.

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of changes, your code works nicely.

I've assumed you wish to use two dice per roll, you can change this number at the top.

The main change is to create a new `current` roll array for each roll rather than keep on adding results to the same one.

```js
var cnt=0; //number of successes
var current=[]; //array for the latest roll
var prevs=[]; //array of arrays of all previous unique rolls
var unique=1; //whether the latest roll is unique
var breaker=0; //emergency stopper for while loop
var goal = 5; // Number of rolls to aim for
var numberOfDicePerRoll = 2; // Number of dice per roll

function compare() { //checks the latest roll array against all previous arrays
    for (var i=0;i<prevs.length;i++) { //iterate through previous rolls, comparing each against the current roll, returning 0 for unique if any are a match
        if (compareArrays(current,prevs[i])) {
            return 0; 
        }
    }

    prevs.push(current); //if no matches are found, add the latest roll into the previous rolls
    return 1; //return a unique
}

function compareArrays(a,b) { //turn arrays into strings to compare
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}

function dice() { //rolls a random number
  var min = 1;
  var max = 10;
  var toss = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)); 
  return toss;
}

function rollToString(roll) {
  return "[" +roll.join(",") + "]";
}

function main() { //main function
  console.log("Starting rolls: Goal: " + goal)
  while (cnt<goal) {
    breaker++;   
    if (breaker>50) { //this is here in case of emergency 
      break; 
    }

    current = Array.from({ length: numberOfDicePerRoll }, (v,k) => dice());

    unique=compare();   //run the compare function
    if (unique) { 
       console.log("Attempt #" + breaker + " - Rolled unique: " + rollToString(current) + " continuing...");
       cnt++; //only continue the count if roll was unique
    } else {
        console.log("Attempt #" + breaker + " - Rolled duplicate: " + rollToString(current) + " retrying...");
    }

  }
  console.log("Goal reached: rolls:" , prevs.map(rollToString).join(" "))
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You assumed correctly! When I run your code here using the "Run code snippet" button, it works fine, but I'm having trouble with something still. 
#1 is, I tried to copy paste this code into a js playground, in this case runjs.co, and it behaves differently from here. IE. It's giving me the problem I initially had, which is current is somehow always being pushed to prevs during compare, seemingly before the for loop is finished, so there is always a match found no matter what the roll is.

Comment: #2 is, I'm running this code as a part of a UXP plugin for photoshop, and it's giving me the same behavior. The compare function behaves as if ```prevs.push(current);``` is always ran, regardless of the result of the for loop. So there is always a duplicate found. I tested this by ```console.log("checking results: " + current + " against " + prevs[i]);``` inside the for loop, and after 1 loop, prevs[i] would always be the same as current. But if I comment out ```prevs.push(current);``` that behavior stops.

Comment: Is there some mechanism by which  ```prevs.push(current);``` is always ran when the compare() function is called, ignoring the for loop before it?

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what the issue on any other platform might be. Possibly the compare arrays function is always returning false. One could try another implementation. I'd test each piece on the other platforms to try to fund where the problem lies.

Comment: In my testing, I put ```console.log("checking tags: " + current + " against " + prevs[i]);``` at the beginning inside the for loop of the compare function. On Attempt #1, it checks the correct first roll against nothing, which results in unique. But on the second run, it will say "checking the current roll against the same array as the current roll". This indicates to me that somehow the script had assigned the attempt #2's current roll to prevs before checking anything.

Comment: If I remove ```prevs.push(current);``` from the for loop, then every loop will return the same behavior as Attempt #1 again, checking current roll against nothing, result in unique rolls.